# Trying to login with python Requests to website, parameter is missing

Tags: python, authentication, parameters, web

i read about rhe Requests lib and try to log in to this site:www.hvr.co.il by this code:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://www.hvr.co.il'
    MY_TZ= 'XXX'
    MY_PASS='XXX'
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(tz=MY_TZ, password=MY_PASS)
    c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer":"http://www.hvr.co.il"})
    page = c.get('http://www.hvr.co.il/cart.aspx')
```

i can see that there is another patameter, name CN, but its a random value that i cant predict..
any idea how to pass by it?

Comment: I was reading to fast and read just your code before submitting my answer. The hidden input element with name="cn" is probably randomly generated every time the page is loaded and you can't predict it. That's the point! I suppose it is a CSRF protection. Otherwise if the page offers some sort of API you should follow my answer below. That's the way of providing username and password using `requests`.

Comment: i thought it something with this parameter.. but i still didnt understand, how do i pass it?

Comment: You can't pass it by sending the form with requests. You don't know its value, you can't guess or predict it. That's the point of its existence there. It should protect the page and allow only sending the form on the page.

Comment: @cezar: You do know it's value - it's provided in the response to the GET request. Do the initial GET, extract the value of `cn`, and POST it back to the form's target URL (`https://www.hvr.co.il/signin.aspx`).

Comment: @cezar: HTTP CONNECT is used for tunnelling through firewalls, proxies etc. This reflects environment configuration at your end and it should not be relevant to this problem,

Comment: @mhawke yes, you're right. I wrote that below. It is the proxy at work. From my home laptop I can access the site without problem with `requests` and get status code 200.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to predict the value of `cn` - it is provided to you when you do the initial GET. You need to parse the returned HTML form to obtain the value of `cn` (and any other hidden fields with dynamic values, if there are any). Then you need to POST the same value back when you attempt to login.

You could use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the HTML:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.session()
r = s.get('https://www.hvr.co.il')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

data = {t['name']:t.get('value') for t in soup.find_all('input', attrs={'type': 'hidden'})}
data.update({'tz': MY_TZ, 'password': MY_PASS})

r = s.post('https://www.hvr.co.il/signin.aspx', data=data)
```

Or you might find it easier to use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/):

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
r = br.open('https://www.hvr.co.il')
br.form = list(br.forms())[0]    # select the first form
br.form['tz'] = MY_TZ
br.form['password'] = MY_PASS
r = br.submit()
# you should now be logged in if your credentials are right
```

Comment: actually i got 200, but in the line soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content) i get: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @cezar: Strange, I always get response code 200. Perhaps there have been some intermittent issues with the remote server.

Comment: @SomeNiceGuy21: Works for me. Tested in both python 2.7.5 and 3.3.2 with beautifulsoup4 v4.3.2. How did you install BeautifulSoup?

Comment: download it from Easy_Install.. i fixed it, but now the problem is that i get TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable at Find_all

Comment: i got it! i added : data['oMode'] = 'login', and now its good. thanks!

Comment: It seems it is the proxy that I am sitting behind causing the problem. In `curl` it says: `Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.hvr.co.il:443` and immediately after that it sends: `CONNECT www.hvr.co.il:443 HTTP/1.1`. After establishing the connection it issues the GET request. So it is a particular issue in my case and has nothing to do with `requests` or the concerned page.

Comment: @SomeNiceGuy21: glad to hear it. Rather than explicitly adding `oMode`, it might be better to alter the code a little and use `t.get('value', '')` to default to an empty string instead of `t.get('value')` which defaults to `None`. This will ensure that input elements that lack a `value` attribute will be included in the posted data.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to pass the log in data as dictionary, but you should use the authentication classes from `requests`. Try like this:

```
# after import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# your code
login_data = HTTPBasicAuth(MY_TZ, MY_PASS)
c.post(url, auth=login_data, headers={"Referer":"http://www.hvr.co.il"})
# your code
```

I'm assuming the web page you're trying to access uses basic authentication. Eventually you'd need to import another authentication class.

EDIT:

There is an error in the above code. Here is the correction:

```
c.get(url, auth=login_data, headers={"Referer":"http://www.hvr.co.il"})
```

Post is needed for sending the form. In our case we provide the credentials through the requests authentication classes, so the request method should be get.

Comment: Hard to guess. I can't see it from here :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mechanize and I can't tell you anything about it.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with basic HTTP authenication. The problem is that certain hidden form fields need to be sent back to the server when posting the user's login credentials.